# Add a new formula to a dynamic formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to Round the data in my worksheet.  I need to add @round(cell,-3) where cell has a unique function that I don't want to disturb.

AFAIK, I can't use any of the formulas extant in Excel.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a custom format to the cells as `0,` (Solution by John Walkenbach)